# Redis Reconnecting Spring

Tags: spring, redis

When I am using a microservice with redis everything works perfectly. The problem comes when for any reason redis goes down, the microservice goes into a reconnection loop.

[Reconnection Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW1MP.png)

In addition to this, all the requests that come in from that moment on take 2 minutes to resolve.
I am only using one instance of redis and I am using lettuce.

Config:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    RedisProperties properties = properties();
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    configuration.setHostName(properties.getHost());
    configuration.setPort(properties.getPort());
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
}


@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(){
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
    return template;
}
```

I have also put in the .properties file the following property:

```
spring.redis.timeout=5000
```

Can someone help me? Why does it take so long for requests to be resolved when Redis goes down?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and I have to create a custom cache error handler to handle the `RedisTimeoutException` exception. Basically you define how to handle the throwed exception instead of return it to the caller. Follow this [guide](https://dzone.com/articles/safeguard-spring-app-from-cache-failure).
About the timeout value, it is the one set by the redis client used that is different from the `spring.redis.timeout`. In my case it is the lettuce timeout with a default value of 60 seconds. So to have a custom value, you have to change the lettuce client timeout when instantiating the `LettuceClientConfiguration`, more details [here](https://dzone.com/articles/safeguard-spring-app-from-cache-failure)